# Ruby on Rails content_tag is deprecated, but I can't replicate its nesting capabilities using tag

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, nested, tags, content-tag

The project I'm working on requires some of the data table's column titles to be referenced/defined in a footnote below the table.

As it's dynamic content that will be looped over depending on how many of the column titles require footnotes, I need to handle most of this in via models/helpers.  I have been able to replicate the html our US designer wants using `content_tag`, but rubocop is whining about the use of content tag and says I should be using `tag` instead. But I can't get the nesting of the html tags to work at all using the `tag` method.

The section html I'm trying to produce is this (which will be repeated for as many footnotes are needed):

```
<li id="id" class="p-2">
  <dl class="m-0"><dt class="d-inline">Unusual term: </dt>
    <dd class="d-inline">Text with the definition of the term.<a href="#id-ref" aria-label="Back to content">↵</a></dd>
  </dl>
</li>
```

And the `content_tag` based code that works to produce it is this:

```
content_tag(:li,
  content_tag(:dl, [
    content_tag(:dt, 'Unusual term: ', class: "d-inline"),
    content_tag(:dd, [
      'Text with the definition of the term.',
      content_tag(:a, '↵', href: '#id-ref', aria: { label: "Back to content" })
    ].join.html_safe, class: "d-inline")
  ].join.html_safe, class: "m-0"),
id: 'id',
class: "p-2")
```

When I switch to using `tag`, the problem I'm coming up against is getting both the `<dt>` and `<dd>` tags, **which both have content**, to nest inside the `<dl>` tag (and also the `<a>` tag, which also has content, to nest within the aforementioned `<dd>` tag).  The `tag` method only seems to output the last piece of nested content and ignores any other content that precedes it.

This is the nesting of the tag method that I've tried:

```
tag.li id: 'id', class: 'p-2' do
  tag.dl class: 'm-0' do
    (tag.dt 'Unusual term: ', class: 'd-inline') +
      (tag.dd 'Text with the definition of the term.', class: 'd-inline' do
        (tag.a arrow, href: anchor, aria: { label: 'Back to content' })
      end)
  end
end
```

And this is the output it's giving me.

```
<li id="id" class="p-2">
  <dl class="m-0"><dt class="d-inline">Unusual term: </dt>
    <dd class="d-inline"><a href="#id-ref" aria-label="Back to content">↵</a></dd>
  </dl>
</li>
```

As you can see, it's close, but it's missing the text content of the `<dd>` tag, which should be output just before the `<a>` tag starts.

Can anyone help? Is there a way to nest tags without losing content? Or should I just give up and write a partial with the actual html code written out...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now worked out a way to nest these tag methods to achieve the desired html output, using the following code:

```
link = link_to ' ↵', '#id-ref', aria: { label: 'Back to content' }

tag.li(id: 'id', class: 'p-2') do
  tag.dl(class: 'm-0') do
    (tag.dt 'Unusual term: ', class: 'd-inline') +
      (tag.dd ('Text with the definition of the term.' + link).html_safe, class: 'd-inline')
  end
end
```

If anyone has an alternative solution, I'd love to hear it, but I think this will serve for now.

**EDIT TO ADD NEW SOLUTION**

Thanks to @max suggestion of using `concat` to rid me of `#html_safe` I now have a block of code that I, my ux designer and rubocop will all be happy with! Here it is:

```
tag.li(id: 'id', class: 'p-2') do
  tag.dl(class: 'm-0') do
    tag.dt('Unusual term:', class: 'd-inline') + ' ' +
    tag.dd(class: 'd-inline') do
      concat 'Text with the definition of the term.'
      concat tag.a(' ↵', href: '#id-ref', aria: { label: 'Back to content' })
    end
  end
end
```

Thanks again for everyone's input on my question. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like `content_tag` and `tag` are part of rails 6.1.3.1.  It looks like only what is being deprecated is the format of the `tag` helper defaulting to an XHMTL empty tag instead of an HTML 5 type of tag.  There are reports of incorrect behavior by rubocop targeting `content_tag` when it is `tag` which should be targeted.

You might check on the arguments to `content_tag` for empty tags since it might not be defaulting the same way as before.

Comment: So are you saying I should be OK to use ```content_tag``` for the tags that have content and it was maybe my use of ```content_tag``` on the empty tags (such as <li> and <dl> that was causing the errors?

Comment: You might check on the arguments to content_tag for empty tags since it might not be defaulting the same way as before.

Comment: Otherwise if it was me I would assume I could still use `content_tag` and rubocop might be misreporting an alert.

Comment: I've managed to get it to a point where I have all but one of the bits of text content to come through using the ```tag``` method.  I've revised the code in my original question above to reflect. The only one I can't get to work is where I need to have the ```<a>``` tag nested in the ```<dd>``` tag, both with content i.e. ```<dd>content<a>content</a></dd>```.  This surely can't be that unusual a situation to handle using ```tag```?

Answer (score 0):

```
tag.li(id: 'id', class: 'p-2') do
  tag.dl(class: 'm-0') do
    concat tag.dt('Unusual term: ', class: 'd-inline')
    concat tag.dd(class: 'd-inline') do
       concat 'Text with the definition of the term. '
       concat tag.a(arrow, href: anchor, aria: { label: 'Back to content' })
    end
  end
end
```

Each `content_tag` or `tag` has its own string buffer - by using `concat` you output to that string buffer. That lets you output multiple times in the block without dealing with string concatenation and `#html_safe`. This string buffer is the return value of `content_tag/tag`.

This really works no matter if you are using `content_tag` or `tag`.

See:

- https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-concat
- [Using concat and capture to clean up custom Rails helpers](https://thepugautomatic.com/2013/06/helpers/)

Comment: Thanks @max, this is super useful. However, it didn't like the block following ```concat tag.dd(class: 'd-inline') do``` - the text wasn't coming through. But with a bit of a tweak - removing the ```concat``` from before the ```tag.dt``` and ```tag.dd``` and joining them with a ```+ ' ' +``` instead I've got it working. I'll post full code in a proper answer for reference. Thanks again; this has been a great way of ridding me of ```#html_safe```